# How can get untyped object's values?

Tags: c#, asp.net, reflection

I want to get an object typed properties values. Here is my code:

```
 Type tip = Type.GetType(pair.Key.GetType().ToString());

  object uretilenNesne = Activator.CreateInstance(tip);
```

uretilenNesne has correct type but I want to access uretilenNesne's properties values. Do you have any idea?

KR,

Dakmaz

Comment: You should probably replace `Type.GetType(pair.Key.GetType().ToString());` with `pair.Key.GetType();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Do you know the name of the property you want to access at *compile time*? If yes, then you can use the `dynamic` data type:

   ```
   Type tip = Type.GetType(pair.Key.GetType().ToString());

   dynamic uretilenNesne = Activator.CreateInstance(tip);

   var x = uretilenNesne.someProperty;
   ```
2. If you know the name of the property at *run time*, you can use reflection: [Type.GetProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getproperty.aspx) will return a property with a given signature that can be accessed with [PropertyInfo.GetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b05d59ty.aspx) or SetValue. Example:

   ```
   Type tip = Type.GetType(pair.Key.GetType().ToString());
   object uretilenNesne = Activator.CreateInstance(tip);

   PropertyInfo pinfo = tip.GetProperty("someProperty");
   object x = pinfo.GetValue(uretilenNesne, null);
   ```
3. If you don't know the name of the property, use [Type.GetProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyaxdd3x.aspx) to get an array of all the properties.

Comment: +1 or, if you know the type you're expecting at compile-time, you can cast the result of Activator.CreateInstance